# Compile a C++ program with "gcc -c" passes well. Why?

Tags: c++

I have a simple C++ program `test_cpp.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
 { std::cout << __cplusplus << std::endl; }
```

As expected, `gcc test_cpp.cpp` gives me an error

```
test_cpp.cpp:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `std::cout'
test_cpp.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(long)'
test_cpp.cpp:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
test_cpp.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccIJz5Vk.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
test_cpp.cpp:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
test_cpp.cpp:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But `gcc -c test_cpp.cpp` passes well. Why? FYI, I am testing on a Ubuntu 18 VM with `g++ -v` and `gcc -v` providing the same result:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
```

Comment: Time to [read the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.4.0/gcc/).

Comment: Because your error is a *linker* error and "gcc -c compiles source files without linking"

Comment: The results are equivalent.  `-c` only compiles the file.  Given a `cpp` extension, gcc compiles as C++, and succeeds.     Without `-c`, gcc also compiles as C++, but gcc driver goes further and tries to link - but does so with C libraries, and not C++ libraries, so fails to link.

Comment: @Peter You said " Given a cpp extension, gcc compiles as C++, and succeeds." Why gcc cannot do the same at linking stage, that is, linking as c++?

Comment: @zell - because that's the way the driver program is designed.  If invoked as `gcc`, it assumes linking a C program.   If invoked as `g++`, it assumes linking a C++ program (which, among other things, links against C++ libraries.    Since the driver program can accept multiple source files on a command line - with different extensions - it can't make an assumption about how the collection of object files should be linked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gcc`, `g++` are/is the same toolchain, these are just different ways to invoke it. `gcc -c` or `g++ -c` just stops after compilation, means that it does not produce an executable but only a binary file. The tool is able to recognize that the file contains C++ source code so behave accordingly for the compilation phase. And at that phase your code is syntactically correct.

But to produce an executable, there is a link phase where libraries, object files, etc are bounded to each other. And alas, the way you invoke the toolchain matters much more seriously. If you use `gcc` then the C linker phase is invoked, if you use `g++` then it is C++ one. The main difference is the libraries that are used to link to your object code. So:

```
test_cpp.cpp:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `std::cout'
```

is a typical link phase error message meaning that the toolchain is not able to locate `std::cout`  and alike. Of course, you invoked it with `gcc` and `stdout` is a C++ standard library thing.

To compile/link your program use `g++`

```
g++ test.cpp
```

To observe what happens use the verbose mode:

```
gcc -v test.cpp
```

or

```
g++ -v test.cpp
```